# ProgressDialog not getting dismissed in webChromeClient in WebView

Tags: android

I am having below code
but Progress Dialog never gets dismissed even after progress is 100 percent.

```
    try{

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browserwebview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);





     webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                catalogProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
                catalogProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);


                catalogProgressDialog.show();
                catalogProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
                activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);

                catalogProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);

                if(progress == 100 && catalogProgressDialog.isShowing()){
                     catalogProgressDialog.dismiss();                       

                }


            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no!"+ description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
               view.scrollBy(0, view.getContentHeight());


            }


            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });




        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        webView.pageDown(true);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It doesn't even show progress completed.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are on your main UI thread? Have you tried wrapping your

```
 catalogProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

in a Handler?

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                 catalogProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks, I have updated the code fully now in the post, I tried your code getting NullPointerException at `handler.post(new Runnable(){`, any suggestions.

Comment: yes, define a handler in your code, try doing this in the onCreate area: handler = new Handler();  and make sure to define handler as a class variable.